# What is the proper way to send a broadcast from an activity to a service?

Tags: android, accessibility

I have an activity with a button than sends a broadcast to an accessibility service (they're in the same app but different processes). I'm sorry if this was already answered many times but I can't find the proper method to do it. To be clear what I wrote works but I don't know if it's the proper way. I wrote this in the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("roastie_toastie");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And in the accessibility service wrote this:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("roastie_toastie");
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        
    }
};
registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

Does anything else need to be added to the intent and intentFilter to be sure that this broadcast does not consume any battery and is only sent and received inside the app?

Comment: If the activity and the service are in the same process, you do not need to use a broadcast. "Does anything else need to be added to the intent and intentFilter to be sure that this broadcast does not consume any battery" -- no. "is only sent and received inside the app" -- any app can send that broadcast and cause your app to respond. Similarly, any app can receive that broadcast.

Comment: @CommonsWare The activity and the service are in different processes. Should I perhaps tell the receiver which packagename it should expect the broadcast from or does that make absolutely no difference in this case? Obviously no other app will send a broadcast with that action string, I'm just worried about battery usage.

Comment: "Should I perhaps tell the receiver which packagename it should expect the broadcast from too or does that make no difference?" -- `setPackage()` on the `Intent` will prevent other apps from receiving that broadcast. It would not prevent other apps from sending the broadcast. "Obviously no other app will send a broadcast with that action string" -- an attacker might. "I'm just worried about battery usage" -- broadcast receivers do not consume battery, except when receiving a broadcast.

Comment: Ok sorry just one more question, after using `setPackage()` on the `Intent` is there any way to also specify the sender's packageName for the receiver's `IntentFilter` so that it only listens to broadcasts from inside the app?

Comment: I googled *"Specify package name for context-registered receiver"* and got no relevant results. Some said to use `LocalBroadcastManager` but Android Studio warns me that it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any way to also specify the sender's packageName for the receiver's IntentFilter so that it only listens to broadcasts from inside the app?

No, sorry. However, if this is all one app, then you do not need to use `registerReceiver()`.

Presumably, right now, in your manifest, you have a `<service>` element that has `android:process` to have the service run in a separate process from the rest of the app. You can have a `<receiver>` element that has the same `android:process` attribute, to have it run in the same process as the service. If you have the `<receiver>` also be `android:exported="false"`, then only your app can send broadcasts to it. Your sending code would use an explicit `Intent`, identifying the specific `BroadcastReceiver` class.

Once you have your broadcast over to the service's process via that `BroadcastReceiver`, it and the service can communicate via some common process-wide singleton.